# Dynamically resize UITableView in UIViewController created in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

In a UIViewController on a storyboard, I have a UITableView that is sized specifically to have two rows in one section with no header or footer, i.e. the height is `88.0f`. There are some cases when I want to add a third row. So in `viewWillAppear:animated:` (and other logical places) I set the frame to be 44.0f logical pixels higher:

```
CGRect f = self.tableView.frame;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(f.origin.x, f.origin.y, f.size.width, f.size.height + 44.0f);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
```

Nothing controversial; pretty standard resize code, and yet... It doesn't work! The tableView height doesn't change visually. The NSLog statement reports the height I expect (`132.0f`). Is this because I'm using Storyboards? I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Storyboards have nothing to do with this. Autolayout, on the other hand, may. Are you using it ? (btw, by "logical pixels" I guess you mean "points" ?)

Comment: Are you also changing your data source for your table view to include this third row? And are you reloading your table view as well?

Comment: @Gavin - Yes, the data source reports the right count. The third row shows up, but I have to scroll to see it, which is not what I want.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis - I'm not using AutoLayout explicitly (I've set no constraints). Aren't I "using" auto layout by using storyboards?

Comment: Autolayout is an option on the storyboard itself. You enable or disable it for the storyboard, and it's on by default. But you can have it disabled.

Comment: have you try to put those code in `viewDidAppear:animated:` rather than `viewWillAppear:animated` ?

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo Yes, I've tried `viewDidAppear:animated:`, `viewWillAppear:animated:` and `viewDidLoad`, all to no effect.

Comment: I got solution, please see my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set an auto layout constraint for the height of the table view in your storyboard. Then connect the constraint to an outlet in your view controller so you can access the constraint in your code. Have the constraint be set to 88. When you want to change the height of the table view, just change the constraint's constant to 132.

Comment: Interesting. Is that standard practice to change constraints like that? It would never occur to me to do that. Now that I know it works, I'm using it ALL THE TIME.

Comment: I am so happy :) with your answer Gavin ! I can sleep well now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the frame only after the call to `layoutSubviews` is made, which occurs after `viewWillAppear`. After `layoutSubviews` is called on the `UIVIew` you can change the dimensions.

As Gavin suggests, if you have the autolayout enabled you can add the constrains to the UITableView via storyboard, connect the height constraint and modify its value as follow:

```
constraint.constant = 132.0f
```

Otherwise if you have the autolayout disabled you can simply change the frame updating the height, but putting the code in a different method, for example `viewDidLoad:`.

Answer (score 0):

recently I'm try to do what you've do. And I got same problem, `tableview` height won't change. Now I got the solution, you need to call `layoutSubviews` after change the frame. And it work on me.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height + 44.);
    [tableView layoutSubviews];
}
```

don't place it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` because even `layoutSubviews` is called, the frame won't change. place it on `viewDidAppear:`